# Basics of returning a task in from Async Method

Tags: c#, async-await

Please bear with me if it is too obvious! I am not able to differentiate between these two versions.

In first version I am awaiting a thread to complete I/O operation assign the result to a local variable & return the task.

```
    async public Task<int> GetUpdateFromManager(string name)
    {
        int newSalary = 0;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            PayrollDB db = new PayrollDB();
            newSalary = db.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Name == name).FirstOrDefault().Salary;
        });
        return newSalary;
    }
```

Here I await on the return from a task.

```
    async public Task<int> GetUpdateFromManager(string name)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            PayrollDB db = new PayrollDB();
            return db.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Name == name).FirstOrDefault().Salary;
        });
    }
```

Would they always work same. in case of positive results & when database call thwows exception?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Dennis_E, Updated missed a sentence.!

Comment: Why are you using `async` for that at all? Why not just `return Task.Run(...)`?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? if so you should be disposing `PayrollDB` in a `using` statement. And you souldn't use `Task.Run` at all you should just call [FirstOrDefaultAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220208(v=vs.113).aspx) and return the task from that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you. Async-Await tells us to use `Task.Run for compute` bound & `await for I/O bound`. For I/O bound we can always wrap the code in `Task.Run` & return, why there is `Async-Await` keyword at all?

Comment: @Abhijeet: I don't see what you mean. For I/O bound code you don't *want* to use `Task.Run`, because you shouldn't be tying up a thread. Ideally, in an async world when you're waiting for IO to complete, *no* threads are blocked...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they work the same. But there are a couple of problems with them.

1) Don't use `Task.Run` to implement asynchronous methods. Instead, use the asynchronous queries available in EF6 and other database APIs.

2) End your method name with `Async` to follow the [TAP guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: Agree with you I also intended to do that. But async methods exposed by EF is not thread safe, right? Consider, one thread asynchronously updating database another thread trying to read same stuff.